# Library that auto-updates/reloads the current page when the server changes

Tags: javascript, webserver, reload

I'm looking for a Javscript library, server, etc. that will allow me to automatically reload a web page when the version in the server changes.

Update: I understand the technologies involved, and what it would take to implement this. What I'm looking for is something that's **already made**. A script I can include in my HTML file that will monitor the server for me. I mean, why reinvent the wheel? :D

Answer (score 2):

Do an ajax call at set intervals to a server side script passing it a timestamp of the latest file, compare that to the timestamp of the file on the server, and if the one on the server is  newer, then echo back the contents and reload the page.

Comment: That's great, I already started work on my own implementation... But has anyone already done this? :D

Answer (score 0):

You need something like [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29), that lets you send a push message from the server to the client, as soon as a new version is available. The basic idea is to keep an connection open from the client to the server, over this open channel you can send messages to the client which in turn can react to such messages (e.g. by executing JavaScript code to reload the page).

[See this example with a PHP backend](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start) on how to implement Comet.

Answer (score 0):

The must for this kind of technology is [node.js](http://nodejs.org) with the [socket.io](http://socket.io) module.

It allows you to use [WebSockets](http://websocket.org), a channel remaining open between the client and the server, and both of them react to changes when a message is sent either way.

When websockets are not available (not using modern browsers), socket.io fallbacks to long-polling ajax.